# Ifstream cannot open file with amdinistrator rights

Tags: c++, file, text, ifstream

I used this code to try to open and read the file (not empty), but ifstream did not work - it could not open the file: I addded the check on file opening and it showed, that ifstream even did not (could not) open the file.

I gave administrator rights to the program, but ifstream still could not read the file.

I also tried to find a path, where ifstream would read this file, but I did not success, and at last I tried to open file using the absolute path - but result is the same.

The file is situated in the root folder of the program, but I placed it everywhere and nothing changed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    ifstream file("fix.txt");
    if (file)
        cout << "SUCCESSFULL OPENING" << endl;

    while (getline(file, s)) {
        cout << s << endl;
        s += "+";
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you run your program? From where? When you run your program, what is its current directory? Is it the same where the file you try to read is located? Are you ***sure***?

Comment: @some-programmer-dude, I just run file using Visual Studio IDE, I could not find out, what current directory did the program have, but I placed the file in every folder that program has and there is not effect.

Comment: When running from Visual Studio the default current directory will be the project root directory IIRC (or maybe the workspace root?). It is *not* the location where the executable program resides. You can change the directory in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may have access to a more detailed error code by activating exceptions on the stream via

```
file.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
```

Then, you get more details by writing

```
try {
   file.open("fix.txt");
}
catch(std::ios_base::failure& f) {
    // f.what() contains a message, f.code() returns a std::error_code
}
```